# Print n-th item

Tags: python

Doing some homework for my basic python class. This week we are doing a quiz on dictionaries and I'm not quiet understanding it.

The question we have been posed is, Write a function `print_nth_item(data, n)` that takes a list data and an integer `n` as parameters and prints the nth item of the list data, assuming the first item corresponds to an `n` of 0. However this time `n` might not be a valid position in data, eg, asking for the 10th item in a list that only has 5 items will not work. If this occurs you should handle the exception error by printing the text "Invalid position provided".

I have tried but failed to answer the question. My code is:

```
def print_nth_item(data, n):
    """dddd"""
    try:
        if n in data:
            print(data)
    except:
        print('Invalid position provided.')
```

I know this doesn't work but am I on the right track?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  The Zealous Community Moderators have flagged your question for closure because you did not clearly explain why your code doesn't work.   Your question might survive better if you fix up that technicality....

Answer (score 3):

Since it is 0 index, n will give you `n`'th element.

```
def print_nth_item(data, n):
    """dddd"""
    try:
        print(data[n])
    except IndexError:
        print('Invalid position provided.')
```

If you need bare `n`th element (not index based on list) use `n-1`

Complete example:

```
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
n = 9

def print_nth_item(data, n):
    """dddd"""
    try:
        print data[n]
    except IndexError:
        print 'Invalid position provided.'

print_nth_item(data, n)
```

Comment: This should be `except IndexError:` - bare except clauses are EVIL

Comment: I forgot to add. Used the above code. Now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

`n in data` will look for the *value* `n`, not the *index* `n`. To use `n` as the index,  use `data[n]`.

Do this:

```
def print_nth_item(data, n):
    """dddd"""
    try:
        print(data[n])
    except IndexError:
        print('Invalid position provided.')
```

Comment: ahhhh thats what i was wondering! i knew it was searching for the value but i didnt know how to find an index. Thank you very much

Comment: This should be `except IndexError:` - bare except clauses are *EVIL*